# find average upto x number of rows of particular column in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have data in dataframe like the one shown below, data is coming from a website.

`Difference` column is `data-7.3`

`Day` is nothing but serial number starting from `1`

`index` is `average` of rows in `difference` upto the current row multiplied by `day`. for example,

First row in index will have `average(0.19)*1`

Second row in index will be `average(0.19,0.19)*2`

Third row in index will be `average(0.19,0.19,0.17)*3`

```
data    difference  day index
7.49    0.19        1   0.19
7.49    0.19        2   0.38
7.47    0.17        3   0.55
7.46    0.16        4   0.71
7.45    0.15        5   0.86
7.44    0.14        6   1
7.43    0.13        7   1.13
7.43    0.13        8   1.26
7.43    0.13        9   1.39
7.42    0.12        10  1.51
7.41    0.11        11  1.62
7.41    0.11        12  1.73
```

Formula for `index` in Excel would be as shown in image:

[image: Excel Image]

But I don't know how to do that in pandas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.expanding`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.expanding.html) with `mean` and multiple column `day` by [`Series.mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mul.html):

```
df['new'] = df['difference'].expanding().mean().mul(df['day'])
print (df)
    data  difference  day  index   new
0   7.49        0.19    1   0.19  0.19
1   7.49        0.19    2   0.38  0.38
2   7.47        0.17    3   0.55  0.55
3   7.46        0.16    4   0.71  0.71
4   7.45        0.15    5   0.86  0.86
5   7.44        0.14    6   1.00  1.00
6   7.43        0.13    7   1.13  1.13
7   7.43        0.13    8   1.26  1.26
8   7.43        0.13    9   1.39  1.39
9   7.42        0.12   10   1.51  1.51
10  7.41        0.11   11   1.62  1.62
11  7.41        0.11   12   1.73  1.73
```